# Php convert date format from format mm-dd-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have some difficults with PHP Date. I need to change date format from
mm-dd-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd
For example I have date like '12/11/15' and I need to convert it to '2015-12-11'

I've tried smthn like this

```
$date = "12/11/15";
$new_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date))
```

but it doesn't works for me. Could you help me?

Comment: Is the input really mm-dd-yyyy, as you say twice, or mm/dd/yy, as in your example?

Comment: try this brother, $date = strtotime('12/11/2015');

$newdate_format = date('Y-m-d',$time);

echo $newdate_format;

Comment: @FrancisSaul thanks a lot! it works for me!

Comment: @Oleg : welcome brother!